# ER database modelling - payment by credit card and/or cash

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

I have a small problem I'm trying to solve. The task says that the medicine can be paid by either cash or credit card or both. I have to identify entities and relations here. 
My first thought is to represent this through IS-A hierarchy. 
My superclass would be entity Payment, and two subclasses - CreditCard and Cash (names are random, not very important now). 
Credit Card entity has it's unique attributes but Cash ent. doesn't. 
I have to connect all this to a sales order Entity. 
Do you maybe have any idea how this should be done.